# How to create typings for asynchronous methods - method overloading

Tags: typescript

I was wondering how I would implement something like these (This was found in the @types from the node ws(WebSocket) module).

```
on(event: 'close', listener: (this: WebSocket, code: number, reason: string) => void): this;
on(event: 'error', listener: (this: WebSocket, err: Error) => void): this;
on(event: 'upgrade', listener: (this: WebSocket, request: http.IncomingMessage) => void): this;
on(event: 'message', listener: (this: WebSocket, data: WebSocket.Data) => void): this;
```

I'm able to just implement the declarations but as soon as I try and add a function body I get `Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393)`

This is the code that I'm trying to utilize:

```
  on(event: 'message',  cb: (msg: string) => void)  { this.CB_onMsg = cb; }
  on(event: 'close',    cb: () => void)             { this.CB_onClose = cb; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In typescript function declaration can be define multiple times as per our needs but the actual function implementation should be in single time. Else we'll get the error - *Duplicate function implementation*

Unlike other languages, in typescript **return type** also can be overload based on different input params type.

```
function on(event: "message", cb: (msg: string) => void): void;
function on(event: "close", cb: () => void): void;
function on(event: "message" | "close", cb: (msg?: string) => void): void {
    console.log(event);
    cb(event);
}

on("message", msg => console.log(msg));
on("close", () => console.log("no message"));
```

But in reality below single line is more than sufficient

```
function on(event: "message" | "close", cb: (msg?: string) => void): void {
     //implementation
}
```

Comment: Do I then need to switch case the `event` to see which type actually was called?

Comment: Yes since we use the same function so there could be if/else/switch.